# Get Icon from UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, icons

I want to extract the icon of an UWP App to build a Explorer like "Open With" menue.

With the help of [SHAssocEnumHandlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762109(v=vs.85).aspx) i managed to get the associated applications to a given file extension.

With [IAssocHandler::GetIconLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776317(v=vs.85).aspx) i get for UWP Apps (Microsoft Edge) something like:

> @{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_41.16299.371.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge/Files/Assets/MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.png}

If i use [SHLoadIndirectString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb759919(v=vs.85).aspx) on this string i get:

> C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets\MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-100.png

But that is the wrong Icon (has no color or contrast).

In the directory:

> C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets\

Are a lot of different Images. 
I don't understand how to choose the correct icon.

I tried to look up the "AppxManifest.xml" but i looks completly different for different Apps.

For an non UWP App i get  as IconLocation something like:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE

Then i can use:

```
Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()
```

and everything is fine. I didn't finde any way to do the same with an UWP App.

Comment: Have you, please, found something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36559301/403671

Comment: @Simon: I think you might be right, this is the best we can do without a proper API. If you want to submit as an answer I can try to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UWP apps (or Windows Store apps, or apps in what's called sometimes the "AppX application model") information can be queried from official APIs.

These APIs don't have a C# equivalent AFAIK but I've provided sample code to do this in my answer to a similar question here on SO:  [Getting icon of “modern” Windows app from a desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36559301/403671)

The sample application dumps all current loaded Windows Store packages & apps.

Note there is not just *one* icon for a UWP app, there may be many, to be able to adapt to a specific device, form factors, etc. The sample code has a utility that gets the highest scale image for a given resource.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following method works:

1. Open *File Explorer* and type **`C:/Program Files/WindowsApps`** in the adress bar.
2. In the *You dont' have permission to access this folder* dialog click **Continue**. This will require administrator privilages.
3. In the *You have been denied permission to this folder* dialog click **security tab** highlighted in blue.
4. In the *WindowsApps Properties* dialog click **Advanced**.
5. In the *Advanced Security Settings for WindowsApps* dialog click **Continue**.
6. Click the blue text **Change** next to *Owner: TrustedInstaller*.
7. In the *Enter object name to select* textbox in the *Select an object or group* dialog enter **your username** (the one displayed in cmd after `C:/User/` right after opening it).
8. Click the **Check Names** button.
9. Click the **OK** button.
10. In the *Advanced Security Settings for WindowsApps* dialog click **Apply** and then **OK**.
11. **Close File Explorer**.
12. Reopen *File Explorer* and type **`C:/Program Files/WindowsApps`** in the adress bar again.

Now you will see a list of folders. Each corresponds to a UWP app installed on your computer. Some apps are in multiple folders. App's resources are places in the `/Assets` subfolder. You will find there the app's icon too.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help with getting the app's icon. With a folder of dozens of png files how do you know which one is the correct file to use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to combine both,

first check **AppxManifest.xml** and search for `uap:VisualElements` block,

then find `Square150x150Logo` key in it,

then get the related value and find the file in the given address and use it.