# Intercepting VB Messageboxes with icons (vbCritical, vbInformation) in C#

Tags: c#

I have succesfully tested the following code with VB Messageboxes from a Microsoft Word template that have no notification icon. I am able to get the text and close the messagebox.

However, when the messageboxes have an icon, `sb.ToString()` returns an empty string.

Also, `GetWindowTextLength(txtHandle)` returns `0`.
The text handle is identified correctly because the Messageboxes closes at the `SendMessage` command.

I have used Spy++ to analyze the messagebox. Here is a screenshot of the output.
[image]

From what it looks like, there are two windows with class name "Statis" and the code seems to take the first one. I need to get the "*O eroare la salvarea documentului in baza de date.*" text.

What should I change in order to get this text?

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
public static void KillMbox()
{
    for (int h = 0; h == 0;)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        h = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Word");
        if (h != 0)
        {
            IntPtr hAsIntPtr = new IntPtr(h); 
            IntPtr txtHandle = FindWindowEx(hAsIntPtr, IntPtr.Zero, "Static", null);
            int len = GetWindowTextLength(txtHandle);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            GetWindowText(txtHandle, sb, len + 1);
            SendMessage(h, 16, 0, 0);
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a window spy to examine the structure of these different message boxes so you know how to adjust your code?

Comment: @CaiusJard, my work computer has no administration rights so I am not able to install applications.

Comment: Actually you cannot get information in the form where it says that the icon is vbCritical or vbInformation . What you can do the most is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122679/getting-icon-of-modern-windows-app-from-a-desktop-application/36495656#36495656

Comment: What are you actually doing? What is your overall task? Example "I am trying to automate with Word to perform 1000 mail merge operations" -> I want to know if this is an XY problem and there is maybe a better way to solve your original problem rather than solving this "got to find a way to kill the message boxes that appear when I'm trying to automate word to send 1000 mail merges"

Comment: Will a human read these messages or are you hoping to dealing with them programmatically? I ask because it may be possible, once you found a window, to screenshot it and react to the contents of the bitmap rather than the text

Comment: @CaiusJard, I want to deal with them programmatically, with scenarios based on the messsages that are displayed. I have used the windows spy script provided by AHK but it doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I have used the Spy++ app and updated the question with info provided by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the content of the MessageBox using by referring to the second window with class name `Static`, using an index.

The following answer helped me -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685715/10468231

```
public void KillMbox()
{
        IntPtr h = FindWindow("#32770", "Microsoft Word"); 

        if (h != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr TextMesaj = FindWindowByIndex(h, 2);
            int len = GetWindowTextLength(TextMesaj);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len + 1);
            GetWindowText(TextMesaj, sb, len + 1);
            SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, h), 16, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());   
        }
}

static IntPtr FindWindowByIndex(IntPtr hWndParent, int index)
{
        if (index == 0)
            return hWndParent;
        else
        {
            int ct = 0;
            IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
            do
            {
                result = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, result, "Static", null);
                if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
                    ++ct;
            }
            while (ct < index && result != IntPtr.Zero);
            return result;
        }
    }
```